# How to enable authentication in MaxScale in MONGO for production?

Tags: nosql, mariadb, maxscale

We have a MariaBD version using MaxScale to use the NoSQL version using MongoDB driver.

However, the connection is made without authentication and so it is possible to create new databases and collections within MaxScale.

How to enable authentication for connection using nosql protocol.

Thank you very much for everyone's attention.

```
type=listener
service=Read-Write-Service
protocol=nosqlprotocol
nosqlprotocol.user=maxscale
nosqlprotocol.password=password
port=17017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require authentication of clients by adding [`nosqlprotocol.authentication_required=true`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-nosql-protocol-module/#enforce-authentication) in the listener configuration.

Comment: It includes this parameter and even so it allows to open connection without password.

Comment: Once you open the connection, can you actually fetch data or do you get some error when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a section *Bootstrapping the Authentication/Authorization* at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-nosql-protocol-module/#authentication that explains how to take authentication into use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).